# How to authenticate to personal OneDrive with Graph REST API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to write an R package to let users access the files in their OneDrive folders from R. The API is Microsoft Graph.

Everything is working fine with OneDrive for Business (which is basically SharePoint under the hood, as I understand it). However, I can't get it to work with personal OneDrive.

#### Custom app registration, `consumers` authorization endpoint

When I use an app registration under my own AAD tenant, I get the following error from the `consumers` AAD authorization endpoint:

> AADSTS50020: User account 'xxxxx@gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Consumers' and cannot access the application 'd44a05d5-c6a5-4bbb-82d2-443123722380'(AzureRtest_cli) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

#### Custom app registration, `9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad` endpoint

From [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/direct-endpoint-differences?view=odsp-graph-online) it appears that the token should be for the tenant `9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad` instead of the generic `consumers`. When I tried that, I obtained a seemingly valid token. However, talking to the `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive` endpoint results in a cryptic 401 error.

#### Azure CLI app registration, `consumers` endpoint

As a hack, I tried piggybacking off the Azure CLI's app registration. This fails with

> AADSTS65002: Consent between first party application '04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46' and first party resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' must be configured via preauthorization. Visit https://identitydocs.azurewebsites.net/static/aad/preauthorization.html for details

#### Azure CLI app registration, `9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad` endpoint

Finally, I tried using the CLI app registration with this tenant, which also failed:

> unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

What are the exact steps I need to do to get to my personal OneDrive?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't treat your account as a personal account. Please share your request of acquiring the access token by calling `consumers` authorization endpoint.

Comment: @AllenWu Ah, I see I had a bug in my code; I was using 'consumers.onmicrosoft.com' instead of 'consumers'. It works now

Comment: @AllenWu Just to confirm, I should talk to `graph.microsoft.com` to get to my personal Onedrive, not `api.onedrive.com`?

Comment: Yes. You should call talk to `graph.microsoft.com` because the access token is for Microsoft Graph rather than `api.onedrive.com`. You have solved this issue right? Can you post an answer to help others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had a bug in my code: I was using the tenant `consumers.onmicrosoft.com` instead of `consumers`. The process to communicate with Graph for personal OneDrive that worked for me was:

- Use the authorization code flow as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), with the following specs:

  - tenant: `consumers`
  - client id: for my custom app registration
  - scope: `https://graph.microsoft.com/{scope} offline_access openid` where the scope is one of those listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#authentication-scopes)
- Use the API endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`.

With regard to that last point, note that the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/direct-endpoint-differences?view=odsp-graph-online) is incorrect or at least outdated, as it still gives `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0` as the endpoint for personal OneDrive requests.

Comment: The documentation needs some clarification so thanks for bringing it to our attention.  You should use Microsoft Graph for accessing personal OneDrive requests in most cases.  If you do end up needing to talk to the direct API (which for a new app you shouldn't if you aren't already) you can use the direct endpoint that you call out to do so, and you'd use Microsoft Graph to discover the URL. Ultimately the Microsoft Graph API is the right one and we'll update the docs to be more clear.